# Alfresco 5.2 - Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, orm, alfresco, configuration-files

I try to connect a second database with Alfresco 5.2.

I use spring xml file to define configuration :

**db-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />   

    <!-- Activate Spring Data JPA repository support 
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.klinck.mc.repository" /> -->

    <!-- 3) Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities-->    
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/klinck" />
        <property name="user" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="admin" />
        <!--<property name="password" value="#{cipher.decrypt('${jdbc.user.password}')}" /> -->
        <!-- C3P0 Pool Properties -->
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="10" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="200" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="3600" />
        <property name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections" value="300" />
        <property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout" value="3600" />
        <property name="numHelperThreads" value="6" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="200" />
    </bean>

    <!-- 2) Declare a JPA entityManagerFactory -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.klinck.mc.bean" />
        <!-- <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/resources/hibernate/persistence.xml" /> -->
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="hibernatePersistenceUnit" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateVendor" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
          <props>
              <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</prop>
             <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
             <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
          </props>
       </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- 4) Specify our ORM vendor -->
    <bean id="hibernateVendor" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <!-- 1) Declare a transaction manager-->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"> 
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

An I have updated POM.xml file:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager  -->
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
       <version>4.2.4.Final</version>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency> 
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javassist/javassist -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.23.1-GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- meilleure gestion des pools de connexion -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mchange/c3p0 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

But I get errors concerning "entityManagerFactory" bean  like this one :
"java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.verifyProperties"

I found solution here :
http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/121744-jpa-2-0-hibernate-4-0-1-spring-3-1-1-compatibility

But now I have another message
"java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;"

I have noticed that this method is included in hibernate-core-4.2.4.Final.jar
So I suppose it's still a conflict issue.

But I wonder if we can use Hibernate with Alfresco like this way...

What is the best way to use Hibernate with Alfresco ?

Comment: Why do you want to use a 2nd(?) database with Alfresco? And why do you want to use Hibernate "with" Alfresco? What is the background of your question? What do you wan to achieve doing this?

Comment: I need to save application data (functionalities, parameter, user preferences, etc...). It has nothing to do with Alfresco. And alfresco team advise me to create another database in order to not "pollute" alfresco database....(https://community.alfresco.com/thread/237415-create-custom-table)

Comment: If you need that for read only access, I would recommend you to use some kind of small service to fetch that data and provide it within a RESTful interface...

Answer (score 1):

I will not question your motivation to create an extra DB connection assuming you have good reasons for that.
The problem you are experiencing is the result of Alfresco having beans sharing the same names as the ones you are using but requiring different implementations. Your bean definitions are actually overriding Alfresco out of the box beans, when alfresco tries to use those beans assuming a different implementation it breaks.
What I can suggest is for you to use a different bean naming, so that it wont clash with Alfresco's. Or externalize your beans into a separate spring context (Via subsystems).

Comment: I don't succed to do it for the moment but I wonder if I must update my POM like I do or keep initial POM (before hibernate depencies addition)

Comment: Knowing that Alfresco have only removed hibernate in 6.0+, that means that their old hibernate libs would clash with yours and probably result in more problems. I would says you will need to either remove it or rewrite its base package...

Comment: Thank's for these informations.So in this case, can't I use their hibernate libs ? Even if I don't succeed to find their hibernate version used ...

Answer (score 0):

OK,
I close this question because Alfresco team advised me not to use Hibernate at all :
https://community.alfresco.com/thread/237415-create-custom-table